# How to stop signalr connection from hanging everything on multiple open tabs?

Tags: connection, signalr, messaging, freeze

I'm using SignalR 2.2.2 to send users messages from my backend. When a user is logged in, and if other conditions are met, their connection is added to a group with the user's userId on my message hub.

It works great, as long as they have 10 or fewer tabs/windows open. Any beyond that, they're stuck in "Loading..." indefinitely.

It seems to just be getting stuck on $.connection.hub.start();

I don't necessarily need to allow each user an infinite amount of signalr connections, but breaking the entire site for them on 10 open tabs is a problem.

I've tried catching or handling an error, but it still just hangs there.

```
$(function () {

   if (loggedInUser != null)
      {

   var user = loggedInUser.UserId;
    var messaging = $.connection.messageHub;


        if (conditions) {
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    messaging.server.joinGroup(user);
            });
        }
     }
});
```

I want to do at least one of the following:

-Just stop adding connections if a limit is reached

-Increase the limit of connections

-If limit is reached, start closing earlier connections

-Try to connect, and after a few seconds if it doesn't work, give up

Comment: did you ever find a solution to any of your requests?